# Automatically create a Google Calendar event when I publish a blog post

Tags: calendar

I would like to configure my site so that, whenever I create a new blog post in a certain category, an event is automatically created in one of my Google calendars. I would also like to set a parameter on the post that controls when the calendar event is scheduled for.

Most of the plugins I've found let me display a Google calendar in my site. Instead of that, I want to create Google Calendar events in response to my Wordpress posts, so that my activity on Wordpress controls what appears on my calendar, not visa-versa.

Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this would be through IFFT connection between Wordpress & Google Calender. It's already done there for you, and there is a tutorial specifically for it. On the downside, you will need to create an IFFT account, and the connection happens outside your server (i.e. you are dependent).

[image]

Check it out at https://ifttt.com/connect/wordpress/google_calendar

PS: IFFT / tutorial might be incompatible with your custom criteria, for that you will have to dig deeper. :/

Comment: Yeah, I looked at IFTTT. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there's a good way for me to set which date an event should appear using it :(

Comment: oh! that's unfortunate. Are you using a custom meta field to store the date? If you are an intermediate coder, you may try directly using google calender api reading the extensive docs and samples given by google.

Comment: And here is an alternative, Zapier it will create an event on the date of your post -  https://zapier.com/apps/google-calendar/integrations/wordpress/10364/create-google-calendar-events-for-new-wordpress-posts